# Stripes in Video with Adobe Air 2.5

Tags: apache-flex, air, adobe, camera

i connected my sony HD video cam to my macBook and get good video quality in my adobe air 2.5 app. But the video got stripes in each moving.

is this a problem of the sony cam or are there some properties to set in my air app?
With my intern webcam of the macbook is everything ok (without any stripes).

damian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any configuration settings in the `flash.media.Camera` class respecting interlacing (the problem you're experiencing), so I would suggest it's an issue with your camera.  There should be some options to configure the recording mode in your camera.  You specifically want your camera to use a *progressive* mode, instead of an *interlaced* mode.  Eg, you'd want to use 720**p** rather than 720**i**.

Comment: thank you for your answer. It is a Sony HDR-HC9 but it supports only 1080i and normal DV mode. This cam works with Adobe Air only in DV mode. in 1080i mode I don't get any input.

Comment: Now the same problem with an older Sony DCR-HC96. Is there no chance to get an stripeless video input like in adobe premiere or final cut? Cameras are connected with FireWire.

Comment: @Mediensache - All DV/Mini-DV-based camcorders I've encountered capture using interlacing.  Most video editing software, like Premiere or Final Cut, have built-in options that enable deinterlacing algorithms/filters on your captures to the PC.  From my searching, the default Flash/Flex libraries do not have such algorithms/filters.  Hence, you'll either need to switch to a camcorder that supports a progressive mode capture, or you need to find a third-party AS3 library that has deinterlacing filters (I'm not aware of any).

Comment: ok thank you merv. I thought if an intern webcam of a macbook shows a video without any stripes, a camcorder do this too. Any other chance to get a video stream into an Adobe Air App? I have to take a picture from a video stream (but without any stripes).